# How can I add a button to a navigation bar programmatically in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add button to navigation bar i want to add the button without any action any help please?

Comment: I would recomand you read Apple's Doc on barbutton items here . https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

```
UIBarButtonItem *yourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Your Button"                                         
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(methodName:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton;
[yourButton release];
```

And then method

```
-(IBAction)methodName {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add UIBarButtonItem to Nav bar instead of UIButton. T do that you can call this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Title"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:nil
                               action:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Comment: @gerg I'm using xib not storyboard

Comment: It doesn't matter, it will work for both. Maybe it will require you to create outlet from nav bar. If you use xib why do you want to add this button programatically? you can do it in IB.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *customBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(customBtnPressed)];
     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:customBtn];
```

///// called event

```
-(IBAction)customBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if UIButton is you really want, try this.

```
    UIButton *btnSample = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnFrame];
    btnSample.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *barBtn_cart = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSample];

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSample;
```